# longtable leaves wrong margins inside list environment

Tags: margins, longtable

Special situation, using longtable inside my custom class. When I use `\longtable`, `\end{longtable}` instead of `\begin{longtable}`, `\end{longtable}`, I get bad margins when the `longtable` is inside a list environment.

Test document:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \begin{document}
  text
  \begin{itemize}
    \item first text
    \begin{longtable}{c}%
      table col1
    \end{longtable}%
      \item second text
    \longtable{c}
    table col2
    \endlongtable
    \item third text
  \end{itemize}
  text
  \end{document}
```

See how the "third text" is out of margin?

I can't remember why I used that syntax when I wrote the class, probably so I got no extra vertical space.

I trace the issue to line 199 in `longtable.sty` -- if the `\endgraf` command is replaced with `\par`, the margins are okay again. Interestingly, `\meaning{endgraf}` shows that its meaning is `\par`.

Is it reasonable to replace the `\endgraf` with `\par`? If I must change the code to use `\begin` and `\end`, do I need to adjust for vertical spacing? I read the code in source2e about the `\begin` and `\end` commands but it looks pretty deep.

Comment: Do you really need a `longtable` in an `itemize` list?

Comment: By the way: `\longtable` screws up the spacings there. You've lost grouping and all spacings go mental

Comment: don't do that !

Comment: @David, you mean don't use that syntax, right? It has been working for years but this is the first time I've heard from a user who put it inside a list environment. If the best thing to do is switch to begin--end syntax I'll do it. Is there any downside (like extra vertical space) to watch out for?

Comment: well that was my initial response. since then I looked at the code and actually it's not as bad as I thought as longtable does group its definitions, I thought it was relying on begin/end. certainly in general you can not rely on using \foo syntax instead of \begin{foo}. the interesting thing you should be showing is \show\par to see what \par is at that point, \show\endgraf will always say \par that is the point, \par can mean anything (and in tables can mean nothing (\@empty))  in any case whatever happens if you use that syntax you are on your own it has never been tested in that usage:-)

Comment: If I run your example with `\show\par` on line 199 of lt I get `> \par=macro:
->\if@newlist \advance \par@deathcycles \@ne \ifnum \par@deathcycles >\@m \@noitemerr {\@@par }\fi \else {\@@par }\fi`  actually that's probably safe enough if you must be in a list.

Comment: thanks to both of your comments I have this working. @Christian, I think this is what you were talking about. I surrounded the `\longtable`, `\endlongtable` with `\bgroup` `\egroup`. It seems to be working now. I need this syntax for reasons that aren't important here.

Comment: @TimA: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to control the spacings of a `longtable` environment with the length variables `\LTleft` and `\LTright`.

Since a first item level is used, it's perhaps an idea to set `\setlength{\LTleft}{\dimexpr\leftmargini+\relltshift}`, where `\relltshift` is some user specified shift relativ to the left margin indent.

```
 \documentclass{article}


 \usepackage{longtable}

 \newlength{\relltshift}

 \setlength{\relltshift}{\labelwidth}
 \setlength{\LTleft}{\dimexpr\leftmargini+\relltshift}

 \begin{document}
 text
  \begin{itemize}
  \item first text
    \begin{longtable}{c}%
      table col1
    \end{longtable}%
  \item second text
    \begin{longtable}{c}
    table col2
    \end{longtable}
  \item third text
  \end{itemize}
  text
\end{document}
```

Comment: my question is a simplified version of what's going on but it does show the problem. I understand I can shift the table in this case since we know it is  in a list but this is for a custom class and I don't know in which environments the longtable will be used.

Comment: @TimA you don't need to know you are in a list, just always set `\LTleft` to `\@totalleftmargin plus 1fill` and it should work in or out of a list.